# How to setup case SLA? Need to reassign case to backup approver queue after it crosses SLA timeline

Tags: apex, case, servicecloud, entitlements

I have requirement to setup SLA on case object.
Req : after case submitted for approval the sla should start and hours would be normal hours (ex.40hrs). After 40 hours if case not get approved then it should route to another backup queue for approval.
How can we achieve this SLA part.
How can  we check every case record is met SLA or not?

Comment: Did you try a formula field and a time based workflow?

Comment: I have tried Entitlement process and milestones. It is working. Thanks